# How to track downloads in android

Tags: android, url, download, google-play

In my application I am trying to track Downloads happening in my device (from Google play store or from any URL s) . I don't want to start any download my app should track of downloads going on in device. When ever Download starts my application should start listening to it. When user starts downloading my application should track `download start time` and when download completes I want to get `end time` and `size of data downloaded`.

Q1. Is there any way to do the above requirement.

Q2. If multiple downloads happening I want to get record of both downloads separately.

Q3. I need to get from which url Download is happening. Or Is it happening from any app like Google play store.

Update:

Q4. Is there any way to capture backgroud running services like download.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @thej is there any workaround you found ?  Please Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do the above requirement.

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

> If multiple downloads happening I want to get record of both downloads separately.

This is not a question.

> I need to get from which url Download is happening. Or Is it happening from any app like Google play store.

This also is not a question.

> Is there any way to capture backgroud running services like download.

I have no idea what "capture background running services" means.